# C++ Inheritance Hierarchy for Numbers

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to implement a Number hierarchy in C++. I'm planning to write an abstract class Number and derive ComplexNumber from Number and derive Real and Imaginary classes from Complex and Integers, Naturals,.. but the problem is when I write NaturalNumber, there are bunch of setters, getters, variables which I don't use in NaturalNumber class.

Can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you give an example for the members which you do not use in `NaturalNumber` ?

Comment: denominal part.(from rational)  
imaginary part. (from complex)
sign. (from integer)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bit of a design problem there :) .

An often useful guidance is to think of inheritance as an **is a** relationship.

If B inherits from A, that means **B is an A**.

With that we mean that B has all the abilities of A.

Obviously this still leaves some room for interpretation and it is the job of a good software architect to fill that :) . 
But it seems quite clear to me that `Natural Number` cannot inherit from `Complex Number`, because it does not have all the properties of a complex number. It doesn't have an irrational part, etc. 
If you really wanted to build hierarchy, it would be

```
Complex Number is a >  Real Number is a > Natural Number is a > Number.
```

And the real and imaginary part of the complex number are are also > Real Numbers.

However, in a practical situation (as opposed to an exercise) you will probably be better off by using a flatter hierarchy.  All of these things are numbers, but it doesn't quite make sense to inherit complex, real and natural number from another. You will likely be better off by just inheriting all of them from `Number`.

There are other ways to re-use code if needed, such as [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), as you already mentioned.

Comment: Yes there is a problem. 
NaturalNumber is a ComplexNumber. 
ComplexNumber has a imaginary part.
NaturalNumber has a imaginary part.

Should I derive all from Number and use composition?

Comment: That hierarchy is just plain wrong. A complex number is *not* a real number. This shows clearly that "numbers" don't actually form an hierarchy. The only thing that can be said is that all those numbers are (in the sense of *is a*) `Number`s. Using composition as you noted is probably the better choice here.

Comment: @DanielJour I see where you are coming from: The Real Numbers can be embedded (by injection) into the complex numbers, but not vice versa. That means that in some sense the set of real numbers is a subset of the set of complex numbers. Which would mean that every real number is a complex one. But: A real number cannot do everything a complex one can do, while (arguably), a complex number can do everything a real one can do. The complex number has extended functionality over the real one and should be the child. But I admit that inheritance isn't the right practical choice here, either way.